# NSIS _?=$INSTDIR switch on ExecWait removes the uninstaller.exe on reboot

Tags: nsis

I have an **NSIS Installer** which calls the uninstaller to uninstall the older version.

ExecWait `$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe /S _?=$INSTDIR` . The `_?` switch is used to make the installer wait till uninstall is complete.

It indeed waits till uninstall is complete. But when i reboot my machine, `uninstall.exe` is not present under `$INSTDIR`.

The uninstaller section has commands to remove some sub-directories under `$INSTDIR` with the `/REBOOTOK` switch.

Ex : `RmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\client`

Will this cause uninstall.exe to be removed on machine reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the position of this `ExecWait` statement in regard of the section that deploy the uninstaller ?

It is possible that the uninstaller removes itself (or try to) and that there is a conflict between it and the "new uninstaller" related to way it removes itself : as an executable cannot be deleted during its execution, instead it marks itself for deletion during the next boot (if you use the `/REBOOTOK` option). After that you are deploying the "new uninstaller" and if it has the same name it is removed on following boot.

You could try to play with the `VIAddVersionKey` statement to define a version for the new installer that is different from the former. Then after installation, check if it is the new or the former unistaller.

Also look at the registry if you have a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` multi_sz value that could contain the name of your uninstaller if it is marked for deletion during next boot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are spot on. The uninstaller tries to delete itself during uninstall -  `Delete /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe`. It can't delete itself while it is running, so it clears the new uninstaller on reboot. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome :o) I just edited my answer for history purpose as I meant `CurrentControlSet` and not `ControlSet001` (I failed  my copy/paste) but you got it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of /REBOOTOK, to remove files that are in use. But `RmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\client` should not remove `$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe`, are you sure you don't have a `RmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR` call in there?

Using /REBOOTOK here is probably not a good idea no matter how you look at it. Once the user reboots all the files in $INSTDIR\client will be deleted (Files from the old install and the new fresh install)

And please quote your paths:

- `ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'`
- `RmDir /r /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\client"`

Comment: Thanks for your time. As @Seki pointed out, the uninstaller was trying to delete itself - `Delete /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe`. I copied the uninstaller to a temporary location and ran it from there - `ExecWait "$INSTDIR\temp\uninstall.exe /S _?=$INSTDIR"`. So that it waits and also it is able to delete the old uninstaller under `$INSTDIR`. And yes i completely agree that REBOOTOK is not a good idea here. But the problem is, the old uninstaller has already been shipped and we have no control over it. I will remove the REBOOTOK switch in the current installer version.